# POSTGRES - INSERT INTO FOREIGN TABLE

Tags: database, postgresql, external, insert-into, postgresql-11

I created a table into an external server

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE external_table (
    field_1 varchar(15) NULL,
    field_2 int4 NULL
)
SERVER server_name
OPTIONS(compression 'pglz', stripe_row_count '500000');
```

Now I want to insert into external_table, but if I run this query

```
INSERT INTO external_table (field_1, field_2) VALUES  ('test',1);
```

It return this error

```
ERROR: operation is not supported
```

How can I add record into a foreign table?

I've tried with the following insert

```
INSERT INTO external_table (field_1, field_2) select 'test',1;
```

It works, but I can't use a INSERT INTO with SELECT statment.

Comment: Which FDW are you using? Please show us the `create foreign server` statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the extension you are using supports "insert into ... select .." but not direct inserts.

you can use you should probably ask this question while specifying the extension.

PS: It looks like the extension you use is cstore_fdw. It does not support direct inserts, because it completely cancels benefits of using columnar storage and create some extra overhead. If you are using cstore_fdw, try to use bulk inserts instead of single row ones. Inserting into a regular table and moving data into cstore_fdw table when data reaches certain size (i.e. stripe_row_count number of rows) is much better option.